# C# How to make a label with a background color not filled 100%

Tags: c#, label, controls, custom-controls

Let me show you an example of what I would like to get:

[image: Label with backcolor not 100%]

Some of the labels are "normal" , other labels are not filled 100%.
To achieve that maybe the label control is not the best item to begin with, but I can't think of a better one. Any idea kind people?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a label since and it looks more like a button. It requires to create a special control that has a [custom paint](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/custom-painting-drawing). [Creating a professional looking GDI + drawn custom control (CodeProject)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6913/Creating-a-professional-looking-GDI-drawn-custom-c) and [Creating Custom Controls (C # Coin)](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f5a10c/creating-custom-controls-in-C-Sharp/).

Comment: You can also take a look at some checks already created like [Krypton Suite of .NET WinForms Controls](https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton).

Comment: You have a choice: You can either draw the pixels in the Paint event or you can assign BackGroundImages. Or you can make the Labels Transparent (which they are by default, btw (and place them over an image (i.e. __nest__ them in a control that shows that image..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use paint for this first create a custom label

```
class HalfColorLabel:Label
{
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Orange);
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            g.FillRectangle(brush,new Rectangle(0,0,this.Width,this.Height/2));
            base.OnPaint(e);
        }
}
```

rebuild the solution

[image]

pick the halfcoloured label

[image]

Comment: really awesome, thx!

Comment: Please vote my answer if it's usefull